# Добрый молодец и красна девица

Tags: фразеология

С красной девицей более-менее понятно: красный - синоним "красивого".
А помните: *"Сказка ложь, да в ней намек, добрым молодцам урок".*
А вот интересно, в каком значении употреблено слово "добрый" по отношению к молодцу? Речь о его характере или "добрый" здесь в значении "хороший" (но не в смысле характера, а в смысле качества)?
*Хотя Гугл на запрос "добрый молодец" сейчас выдает только средство для повышения потенции...*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добрый - от доба (пора), изначально - вошедший в добу, то есть достигший расцвета, полного развития (сильный, крепкий).

Answer (score 1):

"Добры молодцы", так же как "красны девицы", "мил человек", "уважаемый мой", "мил друг", "друже мій"(укр), "mon ami"(фр), "красно золото", "чисто серебро" и т.п. - просто устоявшиеся выражения(формулы) с определённым значением. Русское слово "добрый" восходит к общеславянскому корню *doba- (индоевропейскому* dbabђ- 'соответствовать'), также означавшему 'период времени': сравните значения прилагательных удобный 'подходящий' и подобный 'такой, как'. "Добры молодцы" - должно означать "положительные молодые люди"(большей частью в поэтическом смысле).

***Для справки***. Что же означает слово добрый в русском языке?
Значение слова Добрый по Ефремовой:
Добрый - 1. Благожелательный, отзывчивый, готовый помочь людям (противоп.: злой). // Охотно делящийся с другими своими средствами, имуществом и т.п.; щедрый (противоп.: жадный). 
2. Свойственный доброжелательному, отзывчивому человеку. // Выражающий расположение, сочувствие. // Проникнутый расположением к людям. // Основанный на желании добра людям; нужный, полезный. // Благоприятный, одобрительный. 
3. Связанный с кем-л. взаимным расположением, симпатией, дружбой; близкий. // Основанный на взаимном расположении. 
4. Приносящий удачу, успех; благоприятный. // Содержащий, предвещающий что-л. приятное, радостное. 
5. Ничем не опороченный, не запятнанный; достойный уважения. 
6. разг. Очень хороший. // Опытный, искусный в своем деле. 
7. разг. Значительный по величине, силе и т.п.; большой.

Значение слова Добрый по Ожегову:
Добрый - Делающий добро другим, отзывчивый
Добрый Хороший, отличный
Добрый Хороший, нравственный
Добрый Дружески близкий, милый
Добрый Действительно такой большой, не меньший чем то, что указывается существительным или числительным
Добрый Выражающий эти качества
Добрый Безукоризненный, честный
Добрый Несущий благо, добро, благополучие

Значение слова Добрый по словарю синонимов:
Добрый - добросердечный
сердечный
душевный

Значение слова Добрый по словарю Ушакова:
ДОБРЫЙ 
добрая, доброе; добр, добра, добро. 1. Делающий добро другим; благожелательный, отзывчивый, обладающий мягким характером. Добрый человек. Добрая душа. Доброе сердце. 2..Хороший, нравственный. Добрые дела. 3.Дружески близкий, приязненный (разг.). Мои добрые знакомые. 4. Хорошего качества, добротный (нар.-поэт. обл.). Доброе вино. Добрый конь. 5. Незапятнанный, безукоризненный, достойный, честный. Доброе имя. Добрая память. Добрая слава. 6. Подлинный, действительный, полномерный, не меньший чем... (разг.). Величиною с доброе бревно. У Клима Титькина в избе, как в доброй бане. Д. Бедный. Я просидел добрых два часа. До города добрых пять верст. при добром желании многое можно сделать. Будь добр, будьте добры (разг.) - формула вежливой просьбы. Он так добр, что... (разг.) - любезно соглашается, берет на себя. Она была так добра, что приняла на себя все хлопоты. Твоя (его и т. п.) добрая воля (разг.) - как (тебе, ему) угодно. По доброй воле - по собственному желанию, без принуждения, добровольно. Добрые нравы (устар.) - старинные, неиспорченные нравы. Доброе старое время (ирон.) - недавнее прошлое. Добрый малый (разг.) - человек, отличающийся добрым характером при недалеком уме. **Добрый молодец (нар.-поэт.) - молодой человек, удалец (о действующих лицах в песне или сказке**). Добрые Люди (разг.) - кто- то, какие-то Люди (о лицах, оказывающих услуги). Добрые Люди показали мне дорогу. Люди добрые! (обл. нар.-поэт.) - формула вежливого обращения. Всего доброго! (разг.) - пожелание при прощании. Добрый день, доброе утро, добрый вечер! - приветствия при встрече (днем, утром, вечером). Чего доброго (разг.) - может случиться (при ожидании чего-н. неприятного). Чего доброго нас в дороге гроза застигнет. Добрый час - см. час. По добру, по здорову (добру, здорову - дат. п. кратк. форм к добрый, здоровый) (разг.).

Answer (score 0):

> > Паниковский иногда выходил во двор, озабоченно раскрывал рот ближайшей лошади, глядел в зубы и бормотал: "Добрый жеребец", хотя перед ним стояла добрая кобыла.